# .Net Core 2.2 Generated AzureAD Authentication - InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme and no DefaultChallengeScheme?

Tags: authentication, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I know there's a quite a few questions and answers on this general topic but with .Net Core 2.2, the code required/generated is different.

If you create a new .Net Core 2.2 project in VisualStudio with domain authentication, using AzureAD, you'll be generated a very light project which does authenticate correctly. In Startup.cs you'll find the code below which enables this domain AzureAD Auth and then you use the `[Authorize]` attribute accordingly. The problem is if you try to use it in another .Net Core 2.2 project.

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

I've copied this over along with the proper settings into a .Net Core 2.2 project that I already have created. It's not as light of a project but not extensive and pretty simple. I get the error above, `InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found`

So I'm asking to understand how this is possible? How does a Visual Studio generated .Net Core 2.2 project work with only this code while another project wouldn't?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to add following:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddAzureAD
```

etc...

you can select the schemes in your Authorize attribute:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Comment: I'll try this out. When I do I'm given an exception that says the `CallBackPath` option must be provided. Do you know where this might be referencing?

Comment: Also, if I'm using the above, do I always have to select the authentication scheme on the `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` attribute or will plain `[Authorize]` just work?

Comment: It is part of your options in AddAzureAd(options => options.CallbackPath; i think you will also have to tell the middleware to use authentication e.g.: app.UseAuthentication(); please try out, but i think you will have to provide the custom authentication scheme.

Comment: Ok, I'll mess around. But the thing that still bothers me is if you create a brand new Dotnet Core 2.2 app using Visual Studio, the only code it has under `ConfigureServices` is right above. So I'm trying to understand how is that possible. It doesn't seem right but it works. It works only for that project, nowhere else.